# twitter Bootstrap nav-bar not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using twitter Bootstrap nav bar. 
I am trying to make the nav bar behave properly for the mobile devices(i.e when the screen size is small).

`nav-collapse` works fine in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F4NfT/68/). But for the same code, in the browser when I reduce the window size it does not work. I don't know what seems to be the problem. Please help me.

**Edit :** included the content of the `head`

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/screen.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src = "jquery-1.9.1.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
    <script src = "jquery-ui.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
    <script src = "jquery.validate.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
    <script src = "1.3.1.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap-wysihtml5.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/lib/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>

    <script src = "bootstrap.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/lib/css/prettify.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/src/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css"></link>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/job.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
```

Comment: Paste your entire header, as some meta's can interfere.

Comment: @LukeOliff I have include the contents of head tag.

Comment: should I change the order of any file that am including??

Comment: what is `1.3.1.js` is this another jQuery version?

Comment: remove it, problem solved